# Redefine html <font size=1-7> in css or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

I'm working on a prototype application which I have included a plugin which uses the **deprecate** html .

Is it possible to define custom sizes in pixels for each of the font sizes between 1 and 7?

Right now I'm considering using zoom/scale css properties but would rather define each one individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible;

```
font[size='1'] {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqr9sajw/)